# OneHotEncoding : TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to fit OneHotEncoder on the X_train and then transform on X_train, X_test
However this resulted in error:

```
# One hot encoding 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encode_columns = ['borough','building_class_category', 'commercial_units','residential_units']

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(X_train[encode_columns])
X_train = enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns])
X_test = enc.transform(X_test[encode_columns])
X_train.head()
```

Error:

```
      4 
      5 enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
----> 6 enc.fit(X_train[encode_columns])
      7 X_train = enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns])
      8 X_test = enc.transform(X_test[encode_columns])

TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Sample row of X_train:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a sample row for X_train

Comment: @AhmadAnis I just added it to the question

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue, and is working fine at my side.

Comment: Always provide the _full_ error traceback; it can contain valuable debugging information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: You **probably** run the cell with fit and transform multiple times, and `.transform()` doesn't work the way, you think it work.

**Why are you getting this error?**

If you have data definition in one cell:

```py
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'borough': ["Queens", "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Queens", "Brooklyn"],
                        'building_class_category': ["01", "02", "02", "01", "13"], 
                        'commercial_units': ["O", "O", "O", "O", "A"],
                        'residential_units': [1,2,2,1,1]})
```

And fitting one hot-encoder in second one:

```py
encode_columns = ['borough','building_class_category', 'commercial_units','residential_units']

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit(X_train[encode_columns])
X_train = enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns])
```

The cell above would work first time, but since you overwrite `X_train` if you run the cell second time:

```py
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So the first part of the answer will be - have different name for the input and output.

**What does OneHotEncoder `transform` returns?**

If you'll print out `enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns])` you'll get:

```
<5x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 20 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Defaultly the OneHotEncoder `transform` doesn't return the pandas DataFrame (or even a numpy array) but a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix). To get a numpy array yo have to either transform it:

```py
enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns]).toarray()
```

or set `sparse=False` in definition of OneHotEncoder:

```py
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
```

**Bonus: How to have descriptive names of features?**

After setting `sparse=False`, `enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns])` would return numpy array. Even if you would transform it to pd.DataFrame, column names won't tell you much:

```py
pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns]))

#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
#0  0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
#1  1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
#2  0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
#3  0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0
#4  1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
```

To get proper column names, you have to use `get_feature_names_out()` method:

```py
pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns]), columns = enc.get_feature_names_out())

#   borough_Brooklyn    borough_Queens  ... residential_units_2
#0  0.0                 1.0             ... 0.0
#1  1.0                 0.0             ... 1.0
#2  0.0                 1.0             ... 1.0
#3  0.0                 1.0             ... 0.0
#4  1.0                 0.0             ... 0.0
```

Whole code:

```py
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'borough': ["Queens", "Brooklyn", "Queens", "Queens", "Brooklyn"],
                        'building_class_category': ["01", "02", "02", "01", "13"], 
                        'commercial_units': ["O", "O", "O", "O", "A"],
                        'residential_units': [1,2,2,1,1]})
encode_columns = ['borough','building_class_category', 'commercial_units','residential_units']

enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
enc.fit(X_train[encode_columns])
X_train_encoded = pd.DataFrame(enc.transform(X_train[encode_columns]), columns = enc.get_feature_names_out())
```